# Pulling two separate queries based on a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that I need to pull specific info from based on an array. Take the examples below:

```
List1:

[Agent1, Agent2, Agent3, Agent4, Agent5]

Table1:
Agent_Name| Test_ID | Agent_Score
  Agent1  |  0001   |    95
  Agent2  |  0002   |    93
  Agent2  |  0003   |    85
  Agent3  |  0004   |    99
  Agent4  |  0005   |    100
  Agent5  |  0006   |    88
```

I want to know if there is a way to pull this info conditionally -- if Agent_Name exists in the list above, pull only that Agent's records. If their name doesn't exist, pull every record. I got as far as the first part using session_user():

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE session_user() IN (Agent_Name)
```

How do I set a conditional before the SELECT statement? Something along the lines of:

```
CASE WHEN session_user() IN (Agent_Name) THEN (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE session_user() IN (Agent_Name)) ELSE (SELECT * FROM Table1)
```

This is in GoogleSQL.

Comment: Postgres or BigQuery?  Where is the array?

Comment: The array was just to show the list as an example. Using the actual table's column is sufficient (it has every user I would potentially need to pull). That being said, the list of users is small and I could write the list out in the IN() function if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard Sql

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Agent1' Agent_Name, '0001' Test_ID, 95 Agent_Score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent2', '0002', 93 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent2', '0003', 85 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent3', '0004', 99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent4', '0005', 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent5', '0006', 88 
), list AS (
  SELECT Agent
  FROM UNNEST(['Agent1', 'Agent2']) Agent
)
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE Agent_Name IN (SELECT Agent FROM list)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  JOIN list l ON l.Agent = t.Agent_Name
)
```

Above can be refactored to below little less verbose version

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Agent1' Agent_Name, '0001' Test_ID, 95 Agent_Score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent2', '0002', 93 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent2', '0003', 85 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent3', '0004', 99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent4', '0005', 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent5', '0006', 88 
), list AS (
  SELECT Agent
  FROM UNNEST(['Agent1', 'Agent2']) Agent
)
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE Agent_Name IN (SELECT Agent FROM list)
OR NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  JOIN list l ON l.Agent = t.Agent_Name
)
```

> The idea is to use SESSION_USER() or CURRENT_USER() to check for the user's Agent_Name and then return ...

So, finally

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Agent1' Agent_Name, '0001' Test_ID, 95 Agent_Score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent2', '0002', 93 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent2', '0003', 85 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent3', '0004', 99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent4', '0005', 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Agent5', '0006', 88 
)
SELECT *, SESSION_USER() FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE Agent_Name = SESSION_USER() 
OR NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  WHERE Agent_Name = SESSION_USER()
)
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but this wouldn't pull the current user's Agent Name no?

The idea is to use SESSION_USER() or CURRENT_USER() to check for the user's Agent_Name and then return one of the two queries based on whether that value is in the list

Comment: Definitely It will. Just run example and see the output

Comment: Oh, you mean current user not agent name in table? that was not explicitly formulated in question - but just replace fake names with just current or session user function - is this a problem?